# Counting the number of recurrences of an item of a list

Tags: python, list, count

```
l = "Hello world is me"
words_ = l.split()
print(l.split())

for item in words_ :
    if len(item) < 5 :
        print('Words with length less than 6:', item )
    elif len(item) == 5 :
        print('Words with length 5:', item )
```

This is my code, however I want it to print the number of words at the specified length, but instead it prints the words itself. Any suggestions?

Comment: `sum(1 for w in l.split() if len(w)==5)` should do it.

Answer (score 1):

you could count the words in your loop, but it's more pythonic to feed `sum` with a generator comprehension filtered on the word size:

```
>>> l = "Hello world is me"
>>> sum(1 for w in l.split() if len(w)==5)
2
```

another variant is to convert the result of the test to boolean (here the result of the test is *already* a boolean so no need to `bool()` it), and sum that:

```
sum(len(w)==5 for w in l.split())
```

It's ideal for testing one condition, but if you want to count words matching several conditions (`len < 5`, `len == 5`) in one go, the classical loop remains the best choice since it iterates on the list only once and you're naturally using short-circuit evaluation with `if/elsif`, too bad for listcomps but that's life:

```
less_than_5=exactly_5=0
for item in l.split() :
    if len(item) < 5 :
        less_than_5 += 1
    elif len(item) == 5 :
        exactly_5 += 1
```

Comment: @MosesKoledoye: here indeed there is no reason, a potential problem can be that a person generalizes this to *truthiness* of booleans, in which case it can go wrong.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I don't see how it can go wrong. Or may be I don't understand what you mean :)

Comment: try to `sum(x for x in l.split())` for instance. Even if `x` is truthy of falsy, it fails. I think that's what Willem meant.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye: if we do not use `bool(..)` a person can think that `sum(..)` works as a counter. So that `sum(len(x) for x in a)` counts the number of elements in `a` where `len(x)` has truthiness `True`. This of course is not the case. I'm not saying that this answer suggests that, but it can be a bit confusing. But did +1, so no problem :).

Answer (score 1):

You can count the number of elements that satisfy a condition by using:

```
sum(condition for item in iterable)
```

Note that `condition` here must be a boolean (since `True` is `1`, and `False` is `0`, it thus sums up the `True`s and thus counts the number of times the condition is met).

So if you want to count the number of elements that have a length *less than five*, you can write:

```
number_of_words = sum(len(word) < 5 for word in words_)
```

Or for the number of words with length five:

```
number_of_words = sum(len(word) == 5 for word in words_)
```

etc.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the existing answers, you can use `filter` and `lambda` functions to get a count as well:

```
# Python 2.x
l = "Hello world is me"
words_ = l.split()
print "There are", len(filter(lambda x: len(x) < 5, words_)), "words less than 5 long"
print "There are", len(filter(lambda x: len(x) == 5, words_)), "words exactly 5 long"

# Python 3.x
l = "Hello world is me"
words_ = l.split()
print ("There are", len(list(filter(lambda x: len(x) < 5, words_))), "words less than 5 long")
print ("There are", len(list(filter(lambda x: len(x) == 5, words_))), "words exactly 5 long")
```

Comment: Note that this will only work for Python-2.x, since in Python-3.x `filter` returns an iterable, not a list.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem and the print statements without parentheses will stop you even _before_ that :)

Comment: Edited to include a Python 3 version

Answer (score 1):

I'd build a `Counter` first, then it will be easy to extract the information you want.

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> s = "Hello world is me"
>>> c = Counter(len(x) for x in s.split())
>>> c
Counter({2: 2, 5: 2})
```

Alternatively, you can build the `Counter` with

```
c = Counter(map(len, s.split()))
```

The `Counter` tells you that your sentence has two words of length two and two words of length 5.

Getting the number of words with lenght smaller than five:

```
>>> sum(num_words for length, num_words in c.items() if length < 5)
2
```

Since a `Counter` returns `0` by default when a missing key is looked up you can get the same result by issueing

```
>>> sum(c[length] for length in range(1, 5))
2
```

which is probably a little easier to read than the first option.

Getting the number of words with length 5 is very easy:

```
>>> c[5]
2
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to find length of each word then you can count them based on word's length.

Using `range()`, `max()`, and `sum()` [builtin functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) will simplify code a lot:

```
l = "Hello world is me"
words = l.split()
print(l.split())

# create a dict to count words with the same length
lengths = dict.fromkeys(
    range(1, max(len(word) for word in words) + 1),  # range's stop is exclusive
    0,  # default value
)

# count words' length
for word in words:
    lengths[len(word)] += 1

# count all words with length < 6
print(
    'Words with length less than 6:',
    sum(value for key, value in lengths.items() if key < 6)
)

# count all words with length == 5
print(
    'Words with length 5:',
    lengths.get(5, 0)  # faster than sum()
)
```

will print:

```
['Hello', 'world', 'is', 'me']
Words with length less than 6: 4
Words with length 5: 2
```